# How to increment +1 day in mindate of <p:calendar>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to add +1 day in mindate (or) I don't want to accept the condition as in the image, effective date and expiration date as same.
[image]

Here is the code:

```html
<p:calendar id="Jurisdiction_Expiration_Date"
            styleClass="calender_style" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
            required="true" size="10" readonlyInput="true" showOn="both"
            mindate="#{ApplicationManagedBean23.saveRequestMap['JurisdictionEffectiveDate']}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things here:

1. `p:calendar` is deprecated. Please use `p:datePicker`.
2. Use value-binding as demonstrated in the basic example: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/datepicker/datePickerJava8.xhtml
3. Use a modern Java 8 date (only) type like `LocalDate` which makes it easy to add a day: `localDate.plusDays(1)`.
4. Add an Ajax listener where you set the min date based on the changed value and update the component with the min date (which you bind to the bean property).
5. Make sure you are using the correct bean scope.

See also:

- [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes)
- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)